# How to promote (Copy) a Docker image from one repository to another with JFrog Rest API

Tags: python, rest, post, artifactory

I have a repository with all Docker Images. I want to copy all docker images from there to another repository that were used in the last 7 days. I must be a python script and I cannot use curl.

I have figured out everything except the way to copy the image.

```
URL = "https://repo.url/artifactory"
REPOSITORY = "repo-with-all-images"
IMAGE_NAME = "image-name"
VERSION = "latest"
TARGET_REPOSITORY = "repo-to-paste-images"

url = f"{URL}/api/docker/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}/{VERSION}/promote"

payload = {
      "targetRepo": TARGET_REPOSITORY,
      "copy": True,
}

headers = ({"Authorization": token})

status = urllib3.PoolManager().request(method="POST", url=url, body=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
logging.error(status.data)
logging.error(status.headers
```

When running it I get this message:

> ERROR:root:b'{\n  "errors" : [ {\n    "status" : 405,\n    "message" : "Method Not Allowed"\n  } ]\n}'

> ERROR:root:HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Wed, 11 Jan 2023 09:36:13 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-JFrog-Version': 'Artifactory/X.XX.XX XXXXXXXX', 'X-Artifactory-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:-xxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxx:-xxxx', 'X-Artifactory-Node-Id': 'xxx-xxxxxx-xxx', 'Allow': 'HEAD,GET,OPTIONS'})

Comment: Does it work with cURL? To see if this is an Artifactory question or a Python question...

Comment: It seems like the website you are calling does only accept GET HEAD and OPTIONS requests, no POST.

Comment: tried it in postman and i get the same error message there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [Promote Docker Image](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-PromoteDockerImage) REST API, it looks you are using it wrong.

It says:

```
POST api/docker/<repoKey>/v2/promote

{
    "targetRepo" : "<targetRepo>",
    "dockerRepository" : "<dockerRepository>",
    "targetDockerRepository" : "<targetDockerRepository>",
    "tag" : "<tag>",
    "targetTag" : "<tag>",
    "copy": false
}
```

Which means in your case it should be (based on the original code in the question):

```py
URL = "https://repo.url/artifactory"
REPOSITORY = "repo-with-all-images"
IMAGE_NAME = "image-name"
VERSION = "latest"
TARGET_REPOSITORY = "repo-to-paste-images"

url = f"{URL}/api/docker/{REPOSITORY}/v2/promote"

payload = {
      "targetRepo": TARGET_REPOSITORY,
      "dockerRepository": IMAGE_NAME,
      "tag": VERSION,
      "copy": True,
}

headers = ({"Authorization": token, "Content-Type": "application/json"})

status = urllib3.PoolManager().request(method="POST", url=url, body=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
logging.error(status.data)
logging.error(status.headers
```

Comment: now i'm getting this error message: "ERROR:root:b'{\n  "errors" : [ {\n    "status" : 415,\n    "message" : "Unsupported Media Type"\n  } ]\n}'"

Comment: You're probably missing a request header: `Content-Type: application/json`. I'll update the example in the answer.